# cannot change html content multiple times with jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

The idea of this code is when click on a button it should change the button from for ex drop to Enroll.

Here is code containing jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.dropJQ',function () {
         var classIdValue =  this.value;
         var toEnrollBtn = "#" + classIdValue +"ToEnrollButton";
         var toEmpty = "#" + classIdValue +"ToEmpty";
         
         
      $.get("rmov.php", {classID : classIdValue},
      function(response){
          var opeartion = "success";
          if(response == opeartion){
              alert("The drop operation was failed");
          }else{
              alert("The drop operation was successful!"); 
         }
    $(toEnrollBtn).html("<button class = 'enrollJQ'  value = "+classIdValue+" >Enroll</button>");  
      $(toEmpty).html("");      
      
});
    });
    
    }); 
    
    </script>
      <script>
  
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('click','.enrollJQ',function () {
        var classIdValue =  this.value;
        var toEnrolledString = "#" +classIdValue + "ToEnrolledString";
         var toDropBtn = "#" + classIdValue + "ToDropBtn";
     $.get("rsv.php", {classID : classIdValue},
      function(response){
           var opeartion = "success";
          if(response == opeartion){
              alert("The enroll operation was failed");
          }else{
              alert("The enroll operation was successful!"); 
         }   
         $(toEnrolledString).html("Enrolled");
          $(toDropBtn).html("<button class ='dropJQ' value = '"+classIdValue+"' >Drop</button>");
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a subset of code where trigger happens:

```
while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               //echo '<tr><td><a href="InformationPage.php?classID='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].''.'</a> </td>';
                echo '<tr id="trenrolld">';
                echo '<td><a href="InformationPage.php?classID='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].''.'</a> </td>';
                echo '<td id="'.$row['id'].'ToEnrollButton">Enrolled</td>';//<a href="drop.php?classID='.$row['id'].'">Drop</a>
                echo '<td id="'.$row['id'].'ToEmpty"><button class = "dropJQ" value = "'.$row['id'].'" >Drop</button></td>';
               echo '</tr>';
                     }
```

Once I click on a button, the button change from for ex. enroll -> drop, but when I click again the button stays 'Drop'

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to do with your issue at all. Please clarify and create html version with JS to test it in codepen or Jsfiddle.

Comment: @Tadas there ate to options .. one is to enroll and when you click it the 'enroll'button it becoms' drop' button so you can dropped your enrollment .. so when I click on a enroll button it becoms drop button but when i click it agin the button stays 'drop' button

Comment: Can you make this button in HTML language like you have in PHP? Then I could copy HTML and your JQuery code to see live example how it works.

Comment: Check your dev tools console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can check on `click` the text of the button and then change it.

Example:

```html
<button>Enrolled</button>
```

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Enrolled' ? 'Drop' : 'Enrolled');
});
```